# Unhide and hide columns in VBA using Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code and I would like to use Vlookup as a criteria to shorten my Macro as well as to make it transferable to other files. However, I do not know how I can use Vlookup to make "Nov 15" or "Dec 15" as a criteria to hide the previous columns as well as the columns after showing a full year of data. Please help me Thanks!

November 15

```
Sheets("Charts_wkg").Select
Columns("D:X").Select
Selection.Columns.Ungroup

Columns("D:Y").Select
Selection.Columns.Group

Columns("D:Y").Hidden = True

Columns("AL:BB").Select
Selection.Columns.Ungroup

Columns("AM:BB").Select
Selection.Columns.Group
Columns("AM:BB").Hidden = True
Columns("Z:AL").Hidden = False
```

December 15

```
Sheets("Charts_wkg").Select
Columns("D:X").Select
Selection.Columns.Ungroup

Columns("D:Z").Select
Selection.Columns.Group

Columns("D:Z").Hidden = True

Columns("AM:BB").Select
Selection.Columns.Ungroup

Columns("AN:BB").Select
Selection.Columns.Group
Columns("AN:BB").Hidden = True
Columns("AA:AM").Hidden = False
```

January 16

```
Sheets("Charts_wkg").Select
Columns("D:X").Select
Selection.Columns.Ungroup

Columns("D:AA").Select
Selection.Columns.Group

Columns("D:AA").Hidden = True

Columns("AN:BB").Select
Selection.Columns.Ungroup

Columns("AO:BB").Select
Selection.Columns.Group
Columns("AO:BB").Hidden = True
Columns("AB:AN").Hidden = False
```

Comment: And your column names are? Can you give sample? Is it the same as your criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can used the following code to locate the current month and once located once located can use the cell as reference for hidding and unhiding the cells using offset

```
Dim SearchText As String

       SearchText = InputBox("Enter the Text in column which needs to be unhidden")
        Rows("11:11").Select
            Selection.Find(What:="" & SearchText & "", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
       ActiveCell.Select
   '    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.select
```